# Web Scraping Table into Excel Worksheet

Tags: excel, web-scraping, internet-explorer

Good afternoon,

First off....I know using ie for anything isn't great since its not being supported anymore.

I have figured out how to scrape a table but I need to have the table data to be placed in cell A5.  I tried adding .range("A5") to parts of the code but haven't been able to get it to work.  Please see code below:

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

'Clear the range before scraping
    
    ActiveSheet.Range("A5:k5000").ClearContents
    
'Navigating to webpage
    
    Dim ie As Object
    Dim url As String
    url = "https://www.myfueltanksolutions.com/validate.asp"
    
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.navigate url
    
    Do While ie.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
    Do Until ie.readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
    
'Login credentails and submit
    
    Dim idoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Set idoc = ie.document
    
    idoc.all.CompanyID.Value = "CompanyID"
    idoc.all.UserId.Value = "UserID"
    idoc.all.Password.Value = "Password"

    idoc.parentWindow.execScript "submitForm();"
    
    Do While ie.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
    Do Until ie.readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
    
'Scrapging table
    
    Dim tbl As HTMLTable
    Set tbl = ie.document.getElementById("RecentInventorylistform")
    
    Dim rowcounter As Integer
    Dim colcounter As Integer
    rowcounter = 1
    colcounter = 1
    
    Dim tr As HTMLTableRow
    Dim td As HTMLTableCell
    Dim th
    
    Dim mySh As Worksheet
    Set mySh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    For Each tr In tbl.getElementsByTagname("tr")
        
        'Loop thru table cells
        For Each td In tr.getElementsByTagname("td")
            mySh.Cells(rowcounter, colcounter).Value = td.innerText
            colcounter = colcounter + 1
        Next td
        
        colcounter = 1
        rowcounter = rowcounter + 1
    Next tr
    
'Log out and close website

    ie.navigate ("https://www.myfueltanksolutions.com/signout.asp?action=rememberlogin")
    
    ie.Quit
    
'Last updated and message box at completion

    Range("N1") = Now()
    
    MsgBox "Data Imported Successfully.  Press Ok to Continue."


End Sub
```

Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to start from cell A5? If so, you should change the value in `mySh.Cells(rowcounter, colcounter).Value`. Cell A5 is `Cells(5, 1)`, so you should start from `Cells(5, 1)`. You can try to change the code like this:

```
Dim rowcounter As Integer
Dim colcounter As Integer
rowcounter = 5
colcounter = 1
```